# Open an existing activity - mono for android

Tags: android, mono, notifications, android-activity

I am building a mono android app that receives notifications from GCM and opens an activity when then user clicks on the notification.

An issue is occurring when an instance of the activity the notification creates already exists and is the current active activity in the application.  Upon clicking the notification a duplicate activity is created in the application.  The issue is subtle as the new duplicate activity opens in the foreground and looks identical to previous activity, however when the user clicks the back button the duplicate activity is killed but the previous activity remains meaning the user has to click back button twice.

The following is current code used to generate notification and create an activity on click.  I would hope the process would be something like, if activity exists then open existing activity else start new activity.  Appreciate any help thank you.

```
void createNotification(string title, string desc)
{
 //Create notification
 var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

 //Create an intent to show ui
 var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(Messaging));

 //Create the notification
 var notification = new Notification(Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail, title);

 notification.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Sound;

 //Auto cancel will remove the notification once the user touches it
 notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

 //Set the notification info
 //we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
 //when the notification is tapped.
 notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, title, desc, PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0));

 //Show the notification
 notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```